# ajax post request handle data in symfony2 controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

i really don't understand how to handle with post data from ajax request. This is my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: Routing.generate('save'),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     data: {
          title: title,                
          description: description,
          questions: questions,              
         }
  });
```

The only way to get the data inside my controller action is this:

```
$content = $request->getContent()
```

$content is a url parameter string.
Why don't i get the data normally with:

```
$request->get('title')
```

What is the correct way to handle the post data with jquery ajax methd?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

So, i found out the following issue:

In my current project the request looks like this:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17861060/false.png]

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('poll_save'),                
            data: {
                title: title                    
            }
        })
```

The data is requested via **Request Payload** but i don't know why.

In a clean project the request looks like this:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17861060/right.png]

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{path('_demo')}}',                    
                data: {
                    title: 'title',                
                    description: 'description',
                    questions: 'questions',
                    pollid: 1                        
                }
            })
```

Anything in my project is going wrong. Do you have an idea why the data is requested via **Request Payload**?

Answer (score 9):

Do you use the request object in your controller?

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
//...other things to use

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function handleRequestAction() {

        $request = $this->get('request');
        //request your data
        $title   = $request->get('title');
        //or in one line
        $title   = $this->get('request')->request->get('title');
    }
}
?>
```

This is my normal way when I want to get data from an ajax call.
Could you post what $content contains?

I see no problem with posting the data like you did. Constructing a json object might be helpful but the way you're doing it seems fine to me. I did this too.

**EDIT**

Normally you could also access all data in the request by doing this:

```
$all = $request->request->all();
```

Maybe you could then `var_dump()` the variables to see if something is in them.

Comment: content was a string like this: title=sadfsdf&description=&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Bquestion%5D=sdfas&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Bdescription%5D=&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Boptional%5D=false&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Bqtype%5D=1&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Bsort%5D=1&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Bid%5D=357147573695183&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=fsdfasdf&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=safsdf&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Bvalid%5D=true&questions%5B357147573695183%5D%5Badd%5D=true&pollid=

Comment: $request->request->all(); was also empty. only getContent() gaves me any data. when i add the data to the url part, everything is fine. but i need to send the data via the data parameter because the post data can be very large.

Comment: how does your ajax method look like?

Comment: Like yours, but I'm not using the bundle to generate routes (forgot the name of the bundle). Perhaps the problem is that you define a contentType. Did you try to leave it out and see what happens? jQuery Docu says "Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases"

Comment: Is your whole $request variable empty too if you dump it? Because normally you could also access data like $title = $request['title'];

Comment: only getContent() has content, the rest is empty. I left contentType alos empty, it was the same result.

Comment: This is tricky. I'm not sure what I could advise you next. Maybe you could post the route in your routing.yml and the matching controller? Do you have any debug information? Anything e.g. Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools say when the ajax request is successful?

Comment: Do those two examples above differ in using the routing bundle and not using it? Because in one you use Routing.generate and in the other one you're using twigs {{ path('...') }}

Comment: correct, this is a difference, but the return value is also just an url and the routing is correct because the request is going to the correct controller action

Comment: And in the case where you don't use the bundle you also cannot access your data with the normal  $title   = $this->get('request')->request->get('title'); or can you?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct your json object and pass the JSON object to your controller using JSON.stringify.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
var obj = {
      title: title,                
      description: description,
      questions: questions              
};

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: Routing.generate('save'),
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
 data: JSON.stringify(obj)
});
```

Comment: And this is the normal workflow? I thought the ajax mehtod will handle it alone?

Comment: Yes, because $.ajax does not serialize the data to JSON.

Comment: But why can't i use the normal requets methods? I only get the data via $request->getContent()

Answer (score 1):

quiz - form name
 serialize -populate the variables

```
 $.ajax({
            url: $("#quiz").attr("action"),
            data: $("#quiz").serialize(),
            type: 'POST'
 });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
                url: $("#commentForm").attr("action"),
                data: {
                    comment: commentFormID.val()
                },
                type: 'POST'
});
```

Controller - More like what previous comments suggested.

```
$request = $this->get('request');
$usercomment=$request->request->get('parameterName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Json? I meant is a requirement to content type json? if not, this is the way I handle ajax and using FOSRoutingbundle that I can see you are using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit( function(e){       

        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var $formPHP = $form.serializeArray();
        var $url = Routing.generate( 'route_to_use');

        $.post( $url, $formPHP, function(data){
        .....
        });

    });    
});
```

Then in the controller you can use as a normal request.